# Nested XPath not working?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium to grab some data that is nested in XPath.

```
<a href="https://linkhere" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs " target="_blank">Download</a>
```

Unfortunately, this is nested deep within a list of elements with no unique identifiers.

```
<li class="list-group-item">
                <span class="btn btn-primary btn-xs play" title="Play audio" data-i18n="[title]clickToPlay">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
                </span>
                <div class="btn-group pull-right badge-download">
             <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Bitrate</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="" data-stream="" data-duration="282" class="info-link" target="_blank">...</a></li>
                  </ul>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" aria-expanded="false"> 4:42</a>
            <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs " target="_blank">Download</a>
                </div>
            <a class="name" title="Download" data-i18n="[title]clickToDownload" data-src="" href="" target="_blank"> 
                </a>
                                    Escape The Fate - Hate Me

            </li>
```

Now, this just continuously repeats in a bunch of `<li>` elements, but I can't seem to get the first one.

I'm using Selenium in Java for this.

I've tried using getByLinkText `Download` and that didn't work. I tried using XPath for anchor elements at the first index, but that failed to work as well.

## Attempts:

```
    WebElement downloadButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//LI[@class='list-group-item'])[1]"));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Download']")).click();
```

Comment: Have you tried using CSS instead of xpath?

Comment: As you mentioned `this just continuously repeats in a bunch of <li> elements` so you need to show us some of the outerHTML (may be right from the `<ul>` tag or a bit above) so we can traverse down the DOM and identify the intended node.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try with this Xpath?

```
WebElement downloadButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'badge-download')]/.//a[text()='Download']"));
downloadButton.click();
```

Comment: xception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//div[contains(@class,'badge-download')]/.//a[text()='Download']"}

Comment: Maybe the Download text have some especial characters. Try with `.//div[contains(@class,'badge-download')]/.//a[normalize-space() = 'Download']`. If this doesn't work try find only the div. If find the div works try with a findelements with this xpath `driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'badge-download')]/.//a"));` and see how many a links have the List.

Comment: Error on my Xpath:
.//div[contains(@class,'badge-download')]/.//a[normalize-spa‌​ce(**text()**) = 'Download']

Answer (score 0):

With the provided HTML, you could do:

```
WebElement li= driver.findElementByClassName("list-group-item");
li.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='btn-group pull-right badge-download']" + "/a[contains(text(), 'Download')]")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this XPath, it is working:

```
//a[contains(@class,'btn btn-primary btn-xs') and contains(text(),'Download')]
```

In code try this:

```
WebElement downloadBtn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@class,'btn btn-primary btn-xs') and contains(text(),'Download')]"));
downloadBtn.click();
```